# Difficulty on how to get a list inside a list

Tags: java

Im working on a projet for university that tries to emulate the process of choosing a seat in a flight. In ordem to do that I make a register page to get the user's informations and let him log in and choose his seat. The thing is, I made the seats out of buttons, and when the user chooses his seat the button has to store his information. The next time someone clicks on that now unavailable seat, i want it to show the informations of whoever is occupying that seat. Heres the part i think im having problems with

```
    private void Btn_Register_ConfirmarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
    if(!Text_Register_Name.getText().equals("") && !Text_Register_Age.getText().equals("")&& !Password_Register_Password.getText().equals("")){
        aux = Integer.parseInt(Text_Register_Age.getText()); 
        if(aux >= 65){
            Person passanger = new Elder(true,Text_Register_Name.getText(), Text_Register_Age.getText(), Password_Register_Password.getText(), true );
            passangerList.add(passanger);
            Seat seat = new Seat();
            for(int i = 0; i<passangerList.size(); i++){
                seatList.get(i).addPassanger(passanger);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Conta criada com sucesso!");
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) Panel_Main.getLayout();
            cl.show(Panel_Main, "Welcome");
            Text_Register_Name.setText("");
            Text_Register_Age.setText("");
            Password_Register_Password.setText("");
        }
        else if(aux < 18){
            int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Possui autorização de seu responsável?");
            if(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                Person passanger = new Underage(true,Text_Register_Name.getText(), Text_Register_Age.getText(), Password_Register_Password.getText(),true );
                passangerList.add(passanger);
                for(int i = 0; i<passangerList.size(); i++){
                    seatList.get(i).addPassanger(passanger);
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Conta criada com sucesso!");
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) Panel_Main.getLayout();
                cl.show(Panel_Main, "Welcome");
                Text_Register_Name.setText("");
                Text_Register_Age.setText("");
                Password_Register_Password.setText("");
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Menores de idade necessitam de autorização de um responsável");
            }
        }
        else{
            if(!Text_Register_Name.getText().equals("") && !Text_Register_Name.getText().equals("") && !Password_Register_Password.getText().equals("")){
            Person passanger = new Adult(Text_Register_Name.getText(), Text_Register_Age.getText(), Password_Register_Password.getText(), true);
            passangerList.add(passanger);
            for(int i = 0; i<passangerList.size(); i++){
                seatList.get(i).addPassanger(passanger);
            }            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Conta criada com sucesso!");
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) Panel_Main.getLayout();
            cl.show(Panel_Main, "Welcome");
            Text_Register_Name.setText("");
            Text_Register_Age.setText("");
            Password_Register_Password.setText("");
            }

        }       

    }    
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Preencha todos os campos!");
    }
    }
```

The class Person

```
package codigo;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String password;
    private boolean canSit;
    private Seat seat;

    Person() {      
    }
    public Person(String name, String age, String password, boolean canSit) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.password = password;
        this.canSit = canSit;
    }    
    public Seat getSeat() {
        return seat;
    }

    public void setSeat(Seat seat) {
        this.seat = seat;
    }
    public boolean getCanSit() {
        return canSit;
    }

    public void setCanSit(boolean canSit) {
        this.canSit = canSit;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

The class Seat

```
package codigo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class Seat {

    private boolean isFree = true;
    ArrayList<Person> personHoldlist;

    public boolean getIsFree() {
        return isFree;
    }

    public void setIsFree(boolean isFree) {
        this.isFree = isFree;
    }

    public Seat() {
        personHoldlist = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Person> getPersonHoldlist() {
        return personHoldlist;
    }

    public void setPersonHoldlist(ArrayList<Person> personHoldlist) {
        this.personHoldlist = personHoldlist;
    }

    public Seat(ArrayList<Person> personHoldlist, boolean isFree, JButton btn) {
        this.personHoldlist = personHoldlist;
        this.isFree = isFree;
    }
    public void addPassanger(Person person){
        person.setSeat(this);
        personHoldlist.add(person);
    }

}
```

This is the button I'm working with to check if the seat is available and to check if the passenger already seated. In case he did, he can't take another seat.
I have tried mouse clicked and action performed. Do my "ifs" make sense?

```
    private void Btn_A_11MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        for(int i = 0; i<seatList.size(); i++){
            if(seatList.get(i).getIsFree() == true && passangerList.get(i).getCanSit() == true){
                Btn_A_11.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/aviao_projeto/images/selecionado.png")));
                int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Deseja reservar esse assento?");
                if(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    Btn_A_11.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/aviao_projeto/images/ocupado.png")));
                    passangerList.get(i).setCanSit(false);
                    seatList.get(i).setIsFree(false);
                }
                else{
                    Btn_A_11.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/aviao_projeto/images/freeseat.png")));
                }
            }
            else{
                if(passangerList.get(i).getCanSit() == false){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Você já reservou seu assento!");
                }
                else if(seatList.get(i).getIsFree() == false){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Esse assento já foi reservado por:"+passangerList.get(i).getName()+"\nIdade:"+passangerList.get(i).getAge());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to store them with the same index because ill need to check if the seat is available for taking later on the project. But im not sure how to do it
Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean add `Person` to `personHoldlist.add(person);` with index related to that Person?

Comment: @sc0der I want to add a person from the list of people to a seat in the list of seats. Does that makes sense? Because from that later on i'll check if a seat is free and if a person is already seated

Comment: Let's see that!

Comment: Ok, let me ask you what's the type of `seatList`?

Comment: @sc0der i declared  `seatList` like this
`ArrayList<Seat> seatList = new ArrayList();` In the main code

Comment: I have posted a solution, hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Update the `Seat` class and make the list static to make it shared between objects of the Seat

```
public static ArrayList<Person> personHoldlist;
```

, And to retrieve you can call `Seat.personHoldlist.get(index)`

Comment: I tried doing what you said but i was getting an error. I tried doing
`for(int i = 0; i < passangerList.size()-1; i++){
        seatList.get(i).addPassanger(i, passanger);
    }` and the error is gone. My button doesnt work now tho LOL.
Would you take a look at it as well? I'll post the button as an answer

Comment: Ok, let me check that

Comment: updated the class Seat, but im not sure where and how should i use `Seat.personHoldlist.get(index)`. Also, my fix on 
`for(int i = 0; i<passangerList.size()-1; i++){
                seatList.get(i).addPassanger(i, passanger);
            }`
 doesnt allow me to create more than one person now, hmmm, i wonder

Comment: This list will be shared among all `seats` object, check when do you want to check the `passenger` remove if there is no seat or keep if there is a seat for he/her

Comment: I understood the static, but where and how should i put `Seat.personHoldlist.get(index)` ? thats what made me confused

Comment: For example in `Btn_A_11MouseClicked()`  when `getCanSit() == false` remove the passenger from the `Seat.personHoldlist.removeAt(index);`

Comment: Mmm, im under the impression that the problem is in the seatList, maybe still on that `for`. Because now im not able to create a second person, it gives me an error when i try. it says"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0". And when i click the button, the seat should change color, but it is not doing anything, meaning it is not getting through the very first `if` of the button. Weird